# Two expressions in R that should yield the same answer, but they don't

Tags: r

I am new to R and currently working through R for Data Science to teach myself some basics. I am working on the exercises in chapter 5.2.4, and when doing so tried to create two versions of a filtering code, which I was assuming would be equivalent.
For this, I loaded the following packages: 
    `library(nycflights13)` `library(tidyverse)`

I then wanted to filter out those flights from the included flights data set that departed between midnight and 6 am. I used the following codes:

```
d1 <- filter(flights, dep_time >= 0 & dep_time <= 600)  #yields 9344 rows
d2 <- flights[between(flights$dep_time, 0 , 600),]   # yields 17599 rows
d3 <- filter(flights, between(dep_time,0,600))      #again yields 9344 rows
```

I cannot figure out why d2 is different from the others. Can anyone explain?
Thank you for taking the time to answer such a basic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are missing elements which return NA in addition to TRUE/FALSE and when we have NA as one of the logical elements, the row returned will be NA.  That could be the reason that we have more number of rows.

```
sum(between(flights$dep_time, 0 , 600), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 9344
```

The `filter` will take account of the `NA` elements and remove those NA elements

---

One option would be to return the `NA` elements as `FALSE

```
i1 <- between(flights$dep_time, 0, 600)  & !is.na(flights$dep_time)
d2 <- flights[i1,]
dim(d2)
#[1] 9344   19
```

Comment: This helped to understand what is going on. Thank you!